# Selecting a record with several values in two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

In two tables there are records (colors) with different values. I want the result to show only the color that has all the same values in both tables. If any of the values are missing, it should be completely rejected.

[image]

Another example:

Bellow code should return only `BLUE`

```
WITH
t1 as (SELECT 'RED' as COLOUR, ('1') as VALUESY FROM DUAL
       UNION
       SELECT 'RED' as COLOUR, ('2') as VALUESY FROM DUAL
       UNION
       SELECT 'BLUE' as COLOUR, ('1') as VALUESY FROM DUAL
       UNION
       SELECT 'BLUE' as COLOUR, ('2') as VALUESY FROM DUAL),

t2 as (SELECT 'RED' as COLOUR, ('1') as VALUESY FROM DUAL
       UNION
       SELECT 'RED' as COLOUR, ('3') as VALUESY FROM DUAL
       UNION
       SELECT 'BLUE' as COLOUR, ('1') as VALUESY FROM DUAL
       UNION
       SELECT 'BLUE' as COLOUR, ('2') as VALUESY FROM DUAL)

SELECT *
FROM t1
FULL OUTER JOIN t2 ON t2.VALUESY = t1.VALUESY AND t2.COLOUR = t1.COLOUR
```

Comment: Please post text rather than images, and include the result you are expecting to see for your sample data. Also include your current query attempt and output, and explain why it isn't doing what you want. Your description isn't very clear but it sounds like you just need a simple inner join on both columns...?

Comment: @Alex Poole: I think the image was perfectly clear, I would not understand anymore what is wanted now after the edit...

Comment: @user9557556 - [this is primarily about images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557), but most of it applies to data too. The CTE you added is useful - though it doesn't match the data in the image, but you still haven't shown current and expected output. (Cristoph's answer is probably what you want though - but why did you use a full outer join, do you have a reason to think that's necessary?)

Comment: @user9557556 - I know, I`m trying find how to edit this JOIN.

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways you can do this, one is to perform your `FULL OUTER JOIN` and then `GROUP BY COALESCE( t1.COLOUR, t2.COLOUR )` and count whether there are any `NULL` values on either side of the join; if there are then there is an unmatched value (assuming that none of the input values is `NULL`:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 ( colour, valuesy ) as 
  SELECT 'RED',  '1' FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'RED',  '2' FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'BLUE', '1' FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'BLUE', '2' FROM DUAL

CREATE TABLE t2 ( colour, valuesy ) as 
  SELECT 'RED',  '1' FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'RED',  '3' FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'BLUE', '1' FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'BLUE', '2' FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT COALESCE( t1.COLOUR, t2.COLOUR ) AS COLOUR
FROM t1
     FULL OUTER JOIN t2
     ON t2.VALUESY = t1.VALUESY AND t2.COLOUR = t1.COLOUR
GROUP BY COALESCE( t1.COLOUR, t2.COLOUR )
HAVING COUNT( CASE WHEN t1.COLOUR IS NULL OR t2.COLOUR IS NULL THEN 1 END ) = 0
```

**Output**:

```
| COLOUR |
| :----- |
| BLUE   |
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=01d357ad8058f641d27cdc5bcdfc4e50)*

Comment: Smart solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query as well.

```
WITH
t1 as (SELECT 'RED' as COLOUR, ('1') as VALUESY FROM DUAL
       UNION
       SELECT 'RED' as COLOUR, ('2') as VALUESY FROM DUAL
       UNION
       SELECT 'BLUE' as COLOUR, ('1') as VALUESY FROM DUAL
       UNION
       SELECT 'BLUE' as COLOUR, ('2') as VALUESY FROM DUAL),

t2 as (SELECT 'RED' as COLOUR, ('1') as VALUESY FROM DUAL
       UNION
       SELECT 'RED' as COLOUR, ('3') as VALUESY FROM DUAL
       UNION
       SELECT 'BLUE' as COLOUR, ('1') as VALUESY FROM DUAL
       UNION
       SELECT 'BLUE' as COLOUR, ('2') as VALUESY FROM DUAL)
--
-- query starts from here
--
SELECT
    T1.COLOUR
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            T1.COLOUR,
            LISTAGG(T1.VALUESY) WITHIN GROUP(
                ORDER BY
                    T1.VALUESY
            ) VAL
        FROM
            T1
        GROUP BY
            T1.COLOUR
    ) T1,
    (
        SELECT
            T2.COLOUR,
            LISTAGG(T2.VALUESY) WITHIN GROUP(
                ORDER BY
                    T2.VALUESY
            ) VAL
        FROM
            T2
        GROUP BY
            T2.COLOUR
    ) T2
WHERE
    T1.COLOUR = T2.COLOUR
    AND T1.VAL = T2.VAL;
```

Thanks.

Comment: As long as the `listagg()` length can't exceed the `varchar2` size limit. Obviously not a problem with the sample data, but might be possible with the real data...

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT t1.COLOR, t1.VALUE 
FROM TABLE1 t1 
INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON (t1.COLOR = t2.COLOR) AND (t1.VALUE = t2.VALUE);
```

Comment: Sawa Samuel Philipp. I didn't expect to have to explain it as it is just 3 lines of code. It returns every COLOR and VALUE from TABLE1 that is also in TABLE2 through INNER JOINing them on these values.